# Why "TCL C Extension" not work on "tcl 8.6" but work on "tcl 8.5" interpreter?

Tags: c, tcl

I have write an extension for tcl, in c++. It works fine on tcl 8.5 but give the following error in tcl 8.6 (tclsh86 in windows):

> alloc: invalid block: 0000000141CB93D0: 0 0

The code is as follow:

```
#include "tcl.h"
 
extern "C"
{
static int RandomObjCmd(
            ClientData clientData,
            Tcl_Interp* interp,
            int objc,
            Tcl_Obj *const objv[])
{
   Tcl_Obj *resultPtr;
   int rand, error;
   int range = 0;
   if (objc > 2) {
      Tcl_WrongNumArgs(interp, 1, objv, "?range?");
      return TCL_ERROR;
   }
   if (objc == 2) {
      if (Tcl_GetIntFromObj(interp, objv[1], &range) !=
            TCL_OK) {
         return TCL_ERROR;
      }
   }
//   rand = random();
   if (range != 0) {
      rand = range;
   }
   resultPtr = Tcl_GetObjResult(interp);
   Tcl_SetIntObj(resultPtr, rand);
   return TCL_OK;
}

int DLLEXPORT
Randomi_Init(Tcl_Interp* interp)
{
   /* Initialize the stub table interface */
   if (Tcl_InitStubs(interp, TCL_VERSION, 0) == NULL){
        return TCL_ERROR;
   }

   Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, "orandom", &RandomObjCmd, NULL, NULL);

   Tcl_PkgProvide(interp, "random", "1.1");
   return TCL_OK;
}
}
```

I want to know how i can make it work in tcl 8.6?

I

Comment: Hi Aram, it's very difficult to test your code as-is, can you provide a [mcve] that can replicate the issue that you have.

Comment: Hi, the code just should print "range" variable(as its a sample from tcl book), but i dont know why its work on tcl 8.5 but not on 8.6, i change the library to tcl86.lib, now its work on 8.6 but not on 8.5.

Comment: that's because the two libraries link differently

Comment: link differently? You mean the linking procedure is different or the library?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to want to make your extension use a stub-only Tcl? If so:

- You have to compile against `tclstub85.lib` (or, `tclstub86.lib`), not `tcl85.lib` (or, `tcl86.lib`). Otherwise, `Tcl_InitStubs()` won't work as expected.
- Compile against the `TCL_VERSION` you want to be the minimum (i.e., `tclstub85.lib`, will also load into a Tcl 8.6 or greater);

Comment: When i only use tclstub85.lib (or tclstub86.lib) i could not even compile the code and non of the command are available, the error is : `undefined reference to __imp_Tcl_GetIntFromObj`, i use Code::Blocks and link it as tcl85.lib but its not work correctly.

Comment: Are you adding `-DUSE_TCL_STUBS` to your compile flags?

Comment: The `USE_TCL_STUBS` define has to be set prior to including `tcl.h` or you end up linking against a specific Tcl library file. It then becomes up to the OS whether you can load against another version, but the answer usually is “no”.

Comment: How I can add `-DUSE_TCL_STUBS` in Code::Bloacks in windows? @mrcalvin

Comment: I use `#def USE_TCL_STUBS` in my header file @DonalFellows

Comment: Ad Code::Blocks: This would be another question and has been answered before. You want to add this as Build Options > Other Options ... See https://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Creating_a_new_project#Modifying_build_options